# question on Shuffle & sort phase in Hadoop job

Tags: sorting, hadoop, shuffle

In the shuffle & sort phase, a job with m mappers and r reducers may involve up to m × r distinct copy operations. In which scenario are exactly m × r copy operations necessary?
Can someone please help me with  this one.

Thanks